# Aiogram 3.3 how to send a photo to a user

Tags: aiogram

According to [docs.aiogram.dev send_photo](https://docs.aiogram.dev/uk-ua/latest/api/methods/send_photo.html), you can send a photo using bot.send_photo, but I don't understand how to do that in the sample_handler from staff.py. I have not found a solution for this version (3.3.0) of aiogram.

Two files

First file bot.py:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from config_reader import config
from handlers import login
from handlers import staff


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.bot_token.get_secret_value())
    dp = Dispatcher()

    dp.include_router(login.router)
    dp.include_router(staff.router)

    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Second file staff.py:

```
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.types.input_file import BufferedInputFile


router = Router()


class Samples(StatesGroup):
    sample_state= State()


@router.message(F.text == "sample")
async def sample_handler(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    send photo here
    await state.set_state(Samples.sample_state)
```